# How does node-redis method setex() convert Buffer to string?

Tags: node-redis

I'm using [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) and I was hoping that someone could help me to figure out how this library converts `Buffer` to string. I gzip my data before I store it in redis with [node-gzip](https://github.com/Rebsos/node-gzip#readme) and this call returns `Promise<Buffer>`

```
const data = JSON.stringify({ data: 'test' });
const compressed = await gzip(data, { level: 9 });
```

I tested following 2 approaches of saving buffer data into redis

1. Without `.toString()` - I pass the `Buffer` to the library and it will take care of the conversion

   ```
   const result = await redisClient.setex('testKey', 3600, compressed);
   ```
2. and with `.toString()`

   ```
   const result = await redisClient.setex('testKey', 3600, compressed.toString());
   ```

When I try these 2 approaches I don't get the same value saved in redis. I tried to use different params for `.toString()` to match the output of 1) but it didn't work

Reason why I need the saved value in 1) format is that I'm matching value format that what one of php pages generates

My code is working fine without `.toString()` but I would like to know how `node-redis` handles it internally

I've tried to find the answer in the source code and to debug and step into library calls but I didn't find the answer that I was looking for and I hope that someone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like happens in utils.js file:
[utils.js](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L19)

```
if (reply instanceof Buffer) {
    return reply.toString();
}
```

Also use the proper options (i.e. return_buffers):
[node-redis README](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/blob/master/README.md#options-object-properties)

```
redis.createClient({ return_buffers: true });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this and sorry for the delayed response. I've just tested this but the breakpoint never gets hit...  I've found [this stream write](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/blob/da31ade348f9b98ebc5a3164d59a93576a865906/index.js#L948), but I didn't have time to look further. I'm trying to figure out why is  buffer being saved differently in redis when I use explicit `.toSting()` and when I let the redis handle the buffer to string conversion...

Comment: I don't need to read the buffers in node. The issue that I'm having is that when I use `.toString()` on the buffer before I save the value to redis it saves the data in redis that php script cannot decode... But if I don't use `.toString()` and let the redis library handle it, then php can read the redis value without any issues. I'm trying to figure out how exactly is the redis library handling this buffer to string conversion. I'm asking here because on the redis github page they sad to post the questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Your string probably contains a character that needs to be escaped. Maybe try to use phpredis-json? https://github.com/averias/phpredis-json